# Combine data frame with one value for each date with data frame with several entries per date

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I want to merge two dataframes. DF2 has one temperature value for each day while DF1 has several entries for each day. So I want to look up the temperature for one day in DF2 and have it added to every entry of this day in  dataframe 1.

I guess a loop would work best but being quite new to R I can't figure out how it has to look like

```
DF1$Date<-c(1.8.18, 1.8.18, 2.8.18)
DF2$Date<-c(1.8.18, 2.8.18, 3.8.18)
DF2$Temperature<-c(17,18,17)
DF2$Difference<-c(0.5,0.4,0.5)
```

This is the expected output:

```
DF1$Date<-c(1.8.18, 1.8.18, 2.8.18)
DF1$Temperature<-c(17,17,18)
DF1$Difference<-c(0.5,0.5,0.4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly recommend using the tidyverse library for general data wrangling (and lubridate for date manipulation, although you don't necessarily need lubridate for this question).

This could work in your case:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create the dataframes
DF1 <- data.frame(c("1.8.18", "1.8.18", "2.8.18"))
DF2 <- data.frame(c("1.8.18", "2.8.18", "3.8.18"),
                  c(17,18,17),
                  c(0.5,0.4,0.5)
                  )
names(DF1) <- "Date"
names(DF2) <- c("Date", "Temperature", "Difference")

#### OUTPUT ####
> DF1
#    Date
# 1 1.8.18
# 2 1.8.18
# 3 2.8.18

> DF2
#     Date Temperature Difference
# 1 1.8.18          17        0.5
# 2 2.8.18          18        0.4
# 3 3.8.18          17        0.5
```

So above I just recreated your dataframes. DF1 has just the one column, DF2 has 3 columns.

```
# join dataframes by what the "Date" columns have in common

left_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "Date")
```

This should get your expected output.

```
> DF3
#     Date Temperature Difference
# 1 1.8.18          17        0.5
# 2 1.8.18          17        0.5
# 3 2.8.18          18        0.4
```

For more details check out the [join function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.8/topics/join) in dplyr (which is part of tidyverse library).

Answer (score 0):

I would either take your `Date` variable as a date variable or a character variable. I would not use it as a factor variable for this purpose

```
library(tidyverse)
DF1$Date = as.Date(DF1$Date, "%d.%m.%y") 
DF2$Date= as.Date(DF2$Date, "%d.%m.%y") 
left_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "Date")
```

OR

```
DF1$Date = as.character(DF1$Date)
DF2$Date = as.character(DF2$Date)
left_join(x = DF1, y = DF2, by = "Date")
```

Using it as a factor, you will get an error message, and you have a good chance to get it wrong,